# Air Conditioning or air conditioned?

Tags: word-usage

I traveled from Houston to Dallas last August.  If you ask me how I got there, I may say:

A. I was riding in a bus with air conditioner.

B. I was riding in a bus with air conditioning.

C. I was riding in an air-conditioned bus.

Do any of the sentences have problems?

Which one do you think makes most sense to you?  Or which one sounds more natural?

Comment: If I ask you how you got there, I would expect you to begin any of your phrases with "I _rode_ a ....."  _"Was riding"_ would be used if you want to set a time frame in the past and tell about events that happened in the middle of it.  If, for example, I ask you where you were when you learned how to blow spit-bubbles, then I might expect you to begin with "I _was riding_ in...."

Comment: Air conditioning is very common in the United States, especially in motor vehicles.  Most Americans would be surprised if an inter-city bus did *not* have air conditioning.  Furthermore, most Americans would expect a bus in Texas in the summer to need air conditioning -- eastern Texas has hot and humid summers.

Answer (score 7):

An "air conditioner" is a physical unit, and so needs an article. Sentence A needs to be changed to "a bus with an air conditioner".

Otherwise, all 3 sentences make perfect sense, but A is the least likely to be used. The reason is that, as such, it is ambiguous. After all, the next sentence could be, "Unfortunately, the bloody thing was broken, and I sweated all the way."

Although the same could be said of sentence B, since "air conditioning" is a noun which describes a process/result, such ambiguity is very unlikely in practice.

Answer (score 1):

Two of the three are fine 'as is", but they may not be correct depending on the tense of the conversation. Looking at each sentence:

> **B. I was riding in a bus with air conditioning.**

This is fine- although there should be a hyphen between "air" and 'conditioning". Although most people and general spelling and written usage does not put one there, it is standard to do so based on the parts-of-speech of both words. The industry trade association for air-conditioning uses a hyphen too.

> **C. I was riding in an air-conditioned bus.**

This is fine as constructed.

> **A. I was riding in a bus with air conditioner.**

As constructed, this sentence is structurally grammatical, but does not make sense. You could change it to one of the following:

> *A. I was riding in a bus with [***an***] air conditioner.*

This reconstructed sentence could mean any of the following:

- you were on a bus and it had an air-conditioning unit installed that cooled the air;
- you were on a bus and it had an air-conditioning unit    physically
  on the bus (but this says nothing about the temperature of    the air
  on the bus.

The article I used [***an***] is only an example. However, if you use another article it may radically change the meaning of the sentence.

In addition to being mindful of ***verb tense*** [ride/rode/riding/ridden] and ***articles*** [a/an/the], you may also consider the ***preposition*** that you use. In general usage, you are more likely to use "*on a bus*" rather than "*in a bus*". However there are instances where "*in*" is more appropriate or when both *in* and *on* are both appropriate and interchangeable.